# No funciona la sentencia RTRIM en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8

Deseo extraer la palabra sin espacios a la derecha en mysql, ejemplo query:

```
select RTRIM('PALABRA 1 ');
```

resultado:

`PALABRA 1`

Sin embargo, al aplicarlo a mi tabla no surge ningún efecto y los espacios vacíos se mantienen, también realicé pruebas con `TRIM` o `LTRIM` sin resultados. Dato importante: Estoy trabajando desde Workbench, cuando exporto la tabla como .csv y lo visualizo desde excel, me muestra el caracter `Â` en lugar de los espacios, por ejemplo: `PALABRA 1Â`.

Alguien conoce alguna alternativa?. Mi tabla está configurada en UTF-8

Comment: dices _"al aplicarlo a mi tabla"_, pero no muestras como lo _aplicas_. Sugiero que incluyas el código relevante para entender qué es lo que estás haciendo. Si utilizas algún lenguaje o producto, también incluyelo en las etiquetas de la pregunta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente el problema este en **la versión de mysql que estés utilizando**, ya que necesitas al menos **MySQL 4.0** para utilizar esta función ya que en esta versión es que fue incorporado. Revisa la versión y de ser posible descarga una reciente. También pueda ser que la estés utilizando en una sentencia `UPDATE, INSERT o DELETE`, en ese caso debes quitar la palabra `SELECT` y dejar únicamente `RTRIM('PALABRA 1 ')` en la asignación, por ejemplo:

```sql
-- Suponiendo que el nombre tenga un espacio de mas al final.
UPDATE usuario SET nombre = RTRIM(nombre) WHERE id = 73;
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda, amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Eso suele pasar cuando el dato es copiado y pegado desde Excel Word u algún otro aplicativo el cual hace la representación de espacio mediante caracter especial
, usa la siguiente instrucción para reemplazar el caracter, solo ten cuidado si lo aplicas a toda la tabla.

```
UPDATE tabla SET campo = replace(campo, '','Â') WHERE ....;
```